# product with attrributes join mysql query

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a table structure like this here products and attribute_values has many to many relation and attribute_values has one to many relation with attributes. Here is SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77e01e7

table **attributes**

```
id | name
1  | Color
2  | Size
```

table **attribute_values**

```
id | name | attribute_id
1  | Red  | 1
2  | Blue | 1
3  | small| 2
4  | XL   | 2
```

table **attribute_value_product**

```
product_id | attribute_value_id
1          | 1      //XYZ - Red
1          | 3      //XYZ - small
2          | 2      //ABC - Blue
2          | 4      //ABC - XL
```

table **products**

```
id | name
1  | XYZ
2  | ABC
```

How to get the product's attributes, attribute_values and its selected value from single Query like here for product XYZ I want result like this.

```
[
  {
    "attribute": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Color",
        "attribute_value_id": 1,
        "attribute_values": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Red"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Blue"
          } ]
      } ]
  },
  {
    "attribute": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Size",
        "attribute_value_id": 3,
        "attribute_values": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "small"
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "XL"
          }]
      }]
  }]
```

Can it be done in single query?

Comment: You'd normally handle issues of data display ( like compiling bits of json) inside your application code

Comment: No json I will handle I want a query

Comment: Sure. But you're showing us a result that would normally be obtained by parsing a two-dimensional array.

Comment: For help constructing a query capable of returning such an array, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables on their related columns:

```
select *
from products p
inner join attribute_value_product avp on avp.product_id = p.id
inner join attribute_values av on av.id = avp.attribute_value_id
inner join attributes a on a.id = av.attribute_id
```

If you want the attributes in a comma separated list you can group by product and use `group_concat()`:

```
select p.id, p.name, 
       group_concat(a.name order by a.name) attribute_names,
       group_concat(av.name order by a.name) attribute_values
from products p
inner join attribute_value_product avp on avp.product_id = p.id
inner join attribute_values av on av.id = avp.attribute_value_id
inner join attributes a on a.id = av.attribute_id
group by p.id, p.name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a8f0472bdd2a8fa6c917ab73091ce07e).

Comment: no the attribute_values must show selected and rest for drop down list

Comment: @sanu What do you mean *selected* and *drop down list*? This is an SQL query that returns rows and columns. This is what you ask in your question and in your comment:   
*I want a query*.